# IBM WebSphere Application Server: What are "environment entries" for?

Tags: configuration, websphere

In the WebSphere Application Server admin console, there is a section under
*Application servers > server1 > Process definition > Environment Entries*

I don't understand what environment entries are. They are not system properties because they are defined in *Process definition > Java Virtual Machine > Custom properties*.

So what's that? How can they be accessed from within an application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21254153 , official description is;

> Environment entries can be used to specify variables not specific to
>   WebSphere Application Server, but are defined by other elements, such
>   as UNIX®, Language Environment® (LE), or third-party vendors, among
>   others. These variables tend to be operating system-specific.

So they are OS specific (i.e PATH for Windows, LIBPATH for AIX, LD_LIBRARY_PATH for Solaris).

For an example case where usage is necessary; quoting http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v7r0mx/topic/com.ibm.wbit.help.runtime.doc/deploy/topics/rcfglibadapters.html

> If a native library is dependent on other native libraries, the
>   dependent libraries must be configured on the LIBPATH of the JVM
>   hosting the application server (rather than on the native path shown
>   in the above figure) in order for that library to load successfully.
>   You should configure an environment entry by selecting Servers >
>   Application Servers > server_name > Java and Process Management >
>   Process Definition > Environment Entries (where server_name is the
>   name of the server; for example, server1). On the Environment Entries
>   page, create a new environment entry to specify the LIBPATH of the
>   JVM.

You can access these variables by using System.getenv() (not System.getProperties(), which returns custom properties and generic JVM arguments).